# Comparing/Correlating NDVI Rasters with other index Raster

Tags: raster, ndvi, correlation

So, I've created two rasters. One for NDVI and one for another index for surface water from the same orthorectified World-View 2 image. I can visually see how the indexes are inversely proportional. Areas of higher readings in one raster correlate with areas of low readings in the other index and vis-versa.

I'm doing the processing through ArcGIS 10.2.

How would I show this to be the case in a quantifiable way?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Are you looking for a software solution (with a specific software in mind) or are you looking for a metric ? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: All roads to a good solution will begin with a scatterplot.  *How* you construct it depends on what software tools you have available.  There will also be some minor resampling issues to deal with if the two rasters are not co-registered.  You can go further by constructing a local measure of association (such as a correlation computed via GWR or otherwise) and making an entire raster whose values show how the correlation varies over space. If you would like to edit your question to include relevant information about these things, you are likely to get some good, focused, practical answers.

Comment: Thanks Whuber,

I added my software (ArcGIS 10.2) to the question. But I'm not sure how I would know if they are co-registered. They were created from the same WV2 tif file.

Comment: Because they were created from the same image, you should be fine. In general you can inquire about their origins, cellsizes, and coordinate systems. When the cellsizes and coordinate systems agree, the rasters will be co-registered provided the difference between their origins is an integral multiple of the common cellsize. A quick visual check is to draw one image on top of the other *without the default bilinear interpolation,* so that each cell shows up as a discrete block: when the blocks in the two images exactly overlap, they are at least very close to being co-registered.

Comment: I tried to use the Scatter Plot Matrix Wizard but it doesn't recognize the layers I created with the Raster Calculator as layers that can be used. Is there a different format than the default I should use in raster calculator?